# F# memory management best practices for native interop

Tags: memory-management, f#, pinvoke, shared-memory

When interoperating with native code using pointers what is considered the best practice (or what shouldn't be used) for techniques for allocation. As an example let's say I have the struct and external function:

```
[<StructLayout(layoutKind = LayoutKind.Sequential)>]
type SomeFloats = 
    struct
        val count:int
        val arr:nativeint
        new(count, arr:nativeptr<float>) = 
            { count = count; arr = NativePtr.toNativeInt arr}
    end


[<DllImport("dllName")>]
extern int SomeFunc(nativeint pSomeFloats)
```

And some code which calls it:

```
let run () =

    let count = 5

    let mutable val0 = 
        let arr = Array.zeroCreate count
        SomeFloats(count, &&(arr[0]))

    let mutable val1 = 
        let stackPtr = NativePtr.stackalloc (count)
        SomeFloats(count, stackPtr)

    let mutable val2 = 
        let arr = GC.AllocateUninitializedArray(count, pinned = true)
        SomeFloats(count, &&(arr[0]))

    let mutable val3, disp3 = 
        let x = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(count * sizeof<float>)
        SomeFloats(count, NativePtr.ofNativeInt x), 
            { new IDisposable with
                override this.Dispose(): unit = 
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(x) }


    let i = SomeFunc(NativePtr.toNativeInt &&val0)
    let i = SomeFunc(NativePtr.toNativeInt &&val1)
    let i = SomeFunc(NativePtr.toNativeInt &&val2)
    let i = SomeFunc(NativePtr.toNativeInt &&val3)

    //Do more work

    disp3.Dispose()
```

All of `val0` to `val3` will compile however is there any issues with using any of these construction forms? Looking around it seems like `val0` is invalid as the GC may rearrange an array on the heap without warning. This suggests the use of `val2` with `pinned = true` should be preferred.

When `arr` goes out of scope in `val0` and `val2` could they be collected before `SomeFunc` is called?

**Update:**
Seems my instinct is correct here and `val0/2` should be created like this:

```
    let mutable val2, disp2 = 
        let arr = GC.AllocateUninitializedArray(count, pinned = true)
        let h = GCHandle.Alloc(arr, GCHandleType.Pinned)
        SomeFloats(count, &&(arr[0])), 
            { new IDisposable with
                override this.Dispose(): unit = 
                    h.Free() }
```

When `stackPtr` goes out of scope is the contents of the stack retained until `SomeFunc` is called or will the stack be unwound (and the contents of `val1` potentially altered) as soon as the pointer is returned to `val1`?

`val3` seems like the safest option however I'm not sure of the more general implications of using unmanaged memory with `xHGlobal`?